# C - Array returns different values from the same element when put into variable

Tags: c, arrays, file, variables

I'm very new to programming.
My problem in short:

```
arr[0]=1 arr[1]=2 arr[2]= -4
printf("\n Element 0 when in array: %d\n", arr[0]); // Prints 1 as it should
arr[0] = a;
printf(" Element 0 assigned to variable a: %d", a); /* Prints 67 ?? (Elements 1 and 2 
are printed as 0 when assigned different variables.) */
```

I want my "a" variable to return same value as arr[0] (and then do it for two more variables for arr[1] and arr[2])

I have a text file with a few numbers called "Dane.txt", it's contents - "1, 2, -4,".

Here is the full code in which I try to solve a math problem with input taken from a .txt file (I got most of it from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-read-integers-from-a-file-in-C)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    // Initializing the file pointer
    FILE *fs;
 
    char ch, buffer[32];
    int i = 0, arr[100], j = 0;
    int a, b, c, arr2[3];
    
    // Openning the file with file handler as fs
    fs = fopen("Dane.txt", "r");                    // "Dane.txt" contents: 1, 2, -4,
 
    // Read the file unless the file encounters an EOF
    while(1){
        // Reads the character where the seeker is currently
        ch = fgetc(fs);
 
        // If EOF is encountered then break out of the while loop
        if(ch == EOF){
            break;
        }
        
        // If the delimiter is encounterd(which can be
        // anything according to your wish) then skip the character
        // and store the last read array of characters in
        // an integer array
        else if(ch == ','){
 
            // Converting the content of the buffer into
            // an array position
            arr[j] = atoi(buffer);
 
            // Incrementing the array position
            j++;
 
            // Clearing the buffer, this function takes two
            // arguments, one is a character pointer and 
            // the other one is the size of the character array
            memset(buffer, 0, 32);
 
            // clearing the counter which counts the number
            // of character in each number used for reading
            // into the buffer.
            i = 0;
 
            // then continue
            continue;
        }
        else{
 
            // reads the current character in the buffer
            buffer[i] = ch;
 
            // incrementing the counter so that the next
            // character is read in the next position in 
            // the array of buffer
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
        printf("Number [%d]: %d\n", i, arr[i]);
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n Element 0 when in array: %d\n", arr[0]); // Returns 1 as it should
    arr[0] = a;
    printf(" Element 0 assigned to variable a: %d", a); // Returns 67 ??
}
```

Comment: Write `a = arr[0]` instead of `arr[0] = a`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no place in your code where you assign any value to `a`, so when you print the value of `a`, you get whatever garbage happened to be in that area of memory.

```
arr[0] = a;
```

This is an assignment. The left-hand side is the variable assigned *to*, `arr[0]`. The right-hand side is the value assigned to it. If you are not clear on this, you may wish to study a good C reference's section on lvalues and rvalues.